# What's Wrong with This UBOUND?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose the values of `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` are `1`, `2`, and `3`. I wrote the following code.

```
function uboundout(reference)
uboundout=ubound(reference)
end function
```

And I put `=uboundout(A1:A3)` in B1 expecting `3`, but Excel displays `#VALUE!`. There is no problem when I try `worksheetfunction.count` rather than `ubound`. What's wrong here? Thanks for your reading.

Comment: It doesn't work too. The manual says the default is already 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `reference` as a `Range` and use `.value`:

```
Function uboundout(reference As Range)
If reference.CountLarge = 1 Then
    uboundout = 1
    Exit Function
End If
uboundout = UBound(reference.Value)
End Function
```

Comment: @BigBen - sure, edited.

Comment: I wouldn't use `Len`. Maybe `If reference.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then`.

Comment: @BigBen - Done!  Just curious, what might I not have thought about when using `Len()`?

Comment: Fails with something like 2344 in A1, or anything longer than one character. Oh and of course I made a mistake, you can simplify to `If reference.CountLarge = 1`, the `Cells` is redundant.

Comment: Further hint to `Ubound()` function: c.f. [help reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009050)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) stating:  *"Returns a Long data type containing the largest available subscript for the indicated dimension of an **array**." - So applying `UBound` to a range only instead to 2-dim 1-based array created via `.Value` or `.Value2`, OP gets an error message.

Comment: @T.M. that is why I proposed that edit, yep, thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks. I changed `=ubound(reference)` to `=ubound(reference.value)` and this worked.

Comment: @JunyongKim note that you need more of a change than that. Try what you have with `=uboundout(A1)`. It will fail. You need the handle the instance of when `reference` is a single cell.

Comment: Oh I just understood the function of `countlarge` here. Thank you.